# How to get Network Traffic as one number on Linux

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, networking

currently I am using this script to get CPU Load, Memory Load and used Diskspace. Now I want to expand it to also give me Network traffic.

```
top -bn1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | \
           sed "s/.*, *\([0-9.]*\)%* id.*/\1/" | \
           awk '{print "CPU Load> " 100 - $1"%"}'
free | grep Mem | awk '{print "Memory Usage> "$3/$2 * 100.0"%"}'
used=$(df / | awk 'END{print $5}')
echo "Storage Used> "$used
```

The result should look something like this:

```
CPU Load> 82.8%
Memory Usage> 98.7924%
Storage Used> 23%
Network Traffic> 281 byte/s
```

Is there some way to go about that?

Comment: There are so many ways you can do this. ;) When you say network traffic, what do you mean exactly? For example you can ge t statistics from the interfaces themselves some examples: ifconfig -a, netstat -s has loads of detailed stats. As an aside, there are some great apps for gathering, saving or sending statistics for linux. Check out collectd.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the bottom of your comment where you are looking for throughput. in this case, I'd use ifstat (apt-get install ifstat). and in your script. ifstat 1 1 | tail -1 | awk '{ print $1,$2}'. this will give you Kb in and out. you can add them together.

Comment: @CareFree This works fine! Please add this comment as an answer, so you can be propperly rewarded. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I missed the bottom of your comment where you are looking for throughput. in this case, I'd use ifstat

```
apt-get install ifstat.
```

And in your script.

```
ifstat 1 1 | tail -1 | awk '{ print $1,$2}'.
```

this will give you Kb in and out. you can add them together.